# How to get version history of a file in folder in sharepoint using SharePoint REST API using c#?

Tags: rest, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint library with a file in it. I need to get previous versions of the file who created it and when. What is the rest endpoint to fetch those details. I am new to SharePoint. Please help

Comment: Can you provide more info? What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried hitting this rest endpoint https://<server>/sites/<site>/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared%20Documents/general')/files('SampleDocFile.docx')/versions. It gives me results but not the ones expected. I am not getting proper version history containing who made the changes and when.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this rest endpoint to get previous versions of the file by the file id:

```
https://<server>/sites/<site>/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')/items(1)/versions
```

You could add filters at the end to get the information you need:

```
https://<server>/sites/<site>/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')/items(1)/versions?$select=VersionLabel,Created_x005f_x0020_x005f_By,Created
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to get additional information from REST API request You need to use the $expand property. If You need information like who made the update please add '?$expand=CreatedBy' at the end of the request.. so for Your example it will be something like:

```
https:///sites//_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared%20Documents/general')/files('SampleDocFile.docx')/versions?$expand=CreatedBy
```

that way You will have the user who modified the file in 
content>properties>Title

other interesting data is:

- updated>
- content>properties>CheckInComment>
- content>properties>VersionLabel>

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will try it. But there is one more query i don't get all the versions history entries by making this request it just returns one entry could you let me know the possible cause.

Comment: This is strange. Although for sure the shared documents library has versioning settings turned on by default You may double check to be sure in the library settings. Other reason I can think of is insufficient user permissions on the library, You may also check this. Let me know was it one of those. If no, then I will try to point maybe some other reason